# Update entity on DB using doctrine entityManager class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to update a user ( entity name is user ) using doctrine but i can not find a method in the EntityManager class that could do the work.

I have found the methods persist() , remove(), find()... but nothing about update or edit.

Is there something I'm missing or should I just use the createQuery() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find your user object. (Get to a variable)
2. Set new values using entity setters.
3. Finally persist and flush the user object.